# In SQL, how do I work with a table that has to have many (20+) foreign keys?

Tags: sql

So, let's say I want to create a database to work with soccer games. If I want to have a table called *matches* then how do I avoid having to write something like player1_fk, player2_fk [...] player22_fk?
Is there something like an array for SQL?

Comment: What is your current data model and what do you want to model?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do, add the details @Smutje asks, please.

Comment: seems you need an n:m relation, so use an extra table player_per_match

Comment: "*Is there something like an array for SQL*" - this question usually indicates a lack of understanding what normalization is about. Apart from that: support for arrays depends highly on the DBMS being used. Most have no array support whatsoever others have terrific support for them. So you will need to tell us which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, I decided to go for an intersection table. Also, thanks for the warning, I am going to read up on normalization as I am clearly  lacking in this department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a link table:

```
Matches
  ID

Players
  ID

PlayersToMatches
  Match_ID
  Player_ID
```

This is how you usually store many-to-many relations in a relational database.